# Different place here can svn checkout, but there can't

Tags: macos, svn, timeout, svn-checkout

the same code With two Mac, when at home, I can checkout the code from the  svn server successfully, but when I in my office it can't be checked. And the warning message is: `svn: Can't read from connection: Operation timed out`

The operating system is Mac OS X Lion on both

Comment: Sounds like you need to go through a proxy while being at work and at home you don't. Which protocol are you using (svn? https?)

Comment: No, I'm seeing the same thing -it's a gitsvn issue, not a network configuration problem.  git is making the connection, but the timeout is too short and needs to be adjusted.  I see it when I'm getting huge binaries that have been checked in to svn.

Answer (score 0):

Which protocol do u use to connect to your repository? It may happen if your firewall at your office do something with the port used by your protocol.